# Is it possible to add total amount of found records to list filter label?

Tags: laravel, octobercms

I have a list filter that shows approved records (switch). Can I add amount of these records to label of the filter, like `Approved (431)`. Because there will be a lot of records and I have to know number of them.

P.S. Amount of shown records in the bottom of the list isn't comfortable. I need like I wrote =) If there is another good way to display amount of shown records I'll be glad to know.

Answer (score 0):

Get the approved count using following in controller.(User your plugin model as MODEL)

$count =  MODEL::where('status', 'approved')->all()->count();
   $this['approved_count'] = $count;

Then show it on the _list_toolbar.htm partial as you like. 
ex:

{{approved_count}}

Hope this will work.